# Не добавляет ресурсы в R.id

Tags: android, java

привет всем. разметил допустим текствью

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/good"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="OMG"
        />
```

хочу свзять его из кода:  `TextView lvMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.тут_айди);` но джава его не видит вообще, компилировал много раз - все равно. в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Смотря, где вы его разместили. Таким образом разместить вы его должны были в папке res/layout вашего проекта, в одном из файлов XML-разметки, находящихся в этой папке.

Comment: Компилятор его видит - иначе  подсветил  бы ошибкой и соответственно не компилировал.
Промблема в том, что метод findViewById ишет его в макете установленном на экран , а из ресурсов вьюхи нужно "надувать" LayoutInfllate'ом

Comment: Да, естественно, прежде чем работать с findViewById, необходимо установить в Activity разметку, в которой, собственно, эти View и находятся. Делается это с помощью метода класса "Activity" setContentView(),

Comment: или искать там где он есть... кинь всю активити и немного больше кода